# How application that use twitter API is communicating with twitter

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitter

I want to implement similar API as twitter and what to know how it's implemented. I didn't read much about oAuth and didn't develop twitter app.

When user click on button it execute javascript that popup new window with twitter page and user click connect or authenticate an app. How processing is passed back to application and how application know that on twitter side execution is finished and user authorize the app?

Comment: You really should read the twitter documentation first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide callback function/url of your application where twitter returns with access token after the twitter side execution is finished.

Comment: Thanks, I din't tought that after that comment someone will answer this question.